# find the string with maximum number of lower case characters in java 8

Tags: java-8

I need to find the string with a maximum number of lowercases characters from Given List.

This is how i am currently doing

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> list  = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add("Strig a with ABDD");
        list.add("STR dfd  BC dsff");

        OptionalLong max = list.stream().map(s->countLowerCase(s)).mapToLong(i->Long.valueOf(i)).max();
        System.out.println(max);

    }


    private static long countLowerCase(String inputString) {
        return inputString.chars().filter((s)->Character.isLowerCase(s)).count();
    }
```

is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to perform a `map` followed by `mapToLong` as you can use `mapToLong` with the `long` returning function in the first place:

```
    List<String> list  = Arrays.asList("Strig a with ABDD", "STR dfd  BC dsff");

    list.stream()
        .mapToLong(s -> s.chars().filter(Character::isLowerCase).count())
        .max()
        .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

There is no simpler way. If you really wan to get “the string with maximum number of lower case characters” rather than the number only, you can use:

```
list.stream()
    .max(Comparator.comparingLong(s -> s.chars().filter(Character::isLowerCase).count()))
    .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

which will print `Strig a with ABDD`, as this is the string with the maximum number of lower case characters in your list.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Stream` API, I think there is a slightly easier (one-liner?) way to do it.

```
list.stream()
            .flatMap(s -> Stream.of(s.chars()
                    .filter(Character::isLowerCase)
                    .count()))
            .max(Comparator.naturalOrder())
            .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Or the obvious much simpler solution:

```
long max = list.stream()
            .mapToLong(s -> s.chars().filter(Character::isLowerCase).count())
            .max()
            .getAsLong();
```

Comment: Why do you think, `.flatMap(s -> Stream.of(expression))` is simpler than, e.g. `.map(s -> expression)`? Likewise, `mapToLong(…).max()` looks simpler than `map(…).max(Comparator.naturalOrder())` to me, in other words, the OP was already closer to the simplest solution than all previous answers…

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a static methods in `Comparator` interface which may help you to make your above code a little bit shorter:

```
System.out.println(list.stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparingLong(s -> s.chars().filter(Character::isLowerCase).count())).get()
        .chars().filter(Character::isLowerCase).count());
```

Your output will be: `9`

Comment: It’s an unnecessary overhead letting the comparator repeat this evaluation for every comparison if you’re going to do this operation on the result anyway. A `map` followed by a natural comparison is simpler and more efficient, but well, that’s what the OP already had.